# Communicate between PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml

I have a table in database that has 2 columns Name | Age, I display it in a HTML page.

I want to sort the table in HTML page based on a field when the user clicks on it.

I have a PHP function to do the sorting based on a field.

But after obtaining the rows in sorted order in PHP, I'm looking for ways by which I can update the HTML table without navigating away from the page.

Comment: AJAX is how to communicate between PHP and Javascript, but if you want to save the trouble, there are Javascript functions for sorting a table; PHP not required.

Comment: If you do some kind of pagination to your results, you **need** to query the results again with different `order by` clause hence you **need** ajax. If you present all your results at once, you only need javascript as people already told you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do sorting in javascript, without having to communicate with the server.  For example, this code will sort a table based on the content of the Nth column:

```
function sortTable(table, column, skipHeader) {
  // Stick each row into an array.
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = skipHeader ? 1 : 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    rows.push(table.rows[i]);
  }

  // Sort the array based on the innerText of the column'th cell in each row
  rows.sort(function(a, b){ 
    a = a.cells[column].innerText;
    b = b.cells[column].innerText;
    return a < b ? -1 : (b < a ? 1 : 0);
  });

  // Re-order the rows by removing/appending in the sort order
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var container = row.parentElement;
    container.removeChild(row);
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

For example, to sort the first table in the document, on the first column, and skip the header row:

```
sortTable(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0], 0, true);
```

Obviously you'll want to modify this to suit your own tastes, especially the sorting, but it's a lot simpler than having to post the data back to the server, which I think is what you're proposing.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to communicate between the client and server to do this, just sort the table on the client directly.

There is a jQuery plug-in for this that works quite well:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a javascript library to make your tables sortable using javascript instead of php.  I've used it many times, it works great.

[Javascript Sortable Tables by: Stuart Langridge](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

Answer (score 1):

Since others have covered the fact that client-side sorting would work just fine here, I'll just point you to the resource with which I've had the most sucess doing this kind of thing: [Google Data Tables](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/table.html), part of their [Visualization Library](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html). [Here are the deets](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable) on what you can do (spoiler: everything you want and more).